# How to use a single sed command for this?

Tags: sed

I have this question:

Use a single SED command to transform the following text:

```
<h1>this is the h1 header</h1>

<h2>this is the h2 header</h2>

<h3>this is the h3 header</h3>

<h4>this is the h4 header</h4>
```

to this text:

```
  <div>this is the h1 header</div>

  <div>this is the h2 header</div>

  <div>this is the h3 header</div>

  <div>this is the h4 header</div>
```

this the answer I came up with but is there a way to do this in a single command?
f3 is my filename

```
sed -e 's/<h.>/<div>/g' -e 's/<\/h.>/<\/div>/g' f3
```

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the edit. Although I understand you don't want 2 or more `-e`, bear in mind that that is a single command indeed.

Comment: So until I used the keyword 'sed' again, it is a single command only, right?

Comment: Right, it's only one.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus It has nothing to do with HTML, It's just that the professor gave us this practice document for sed command.

Comment: @Cyrus well I've my final exam tomorrow, god help his next batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's|<[^>]*>\(.*\)</[^>]*>|<div>\1</div>|' f3
```

Comment: This one worked, but why are we using pipe( | ) in the sed command? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: The delimiter we see most is `/`, but barely any character is valid. The advantage here is that we don't have to escape the `/` in `/div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sed 's/h[1-4]/div/g' f3
```